# Different font for symbols of Real , rational , whole , integer and natural numbers

Tags: real-numbers, integers, natural-numbers

Why is the symbol for real number , natural number , interfere...written with a different font, specifically one that has a extra line along the main letter ? Is it for easy identification or something else

Comment: Exactly for this reason. $N,R,Z$ are all used commonly elsewhere but $\mathbb{R}$ is quite distinctive.

Comment: It is simply by convention, so it would be easier to understand.

Comment: One reason I heard is because back when people were writing maths on blackboards, the extra line would help the $\mathbb{N,Z,R}$ stand out compared to $N,Z,R$